# Cannot access Azure VM endpoint

Tags: azure, ubuntu-14.04

I created an Ubuntu VM in azure and installed CouchDb on port 5984. `nmap localhost -p5984` shows that the port is opened. I added an endpoint for the VM with the public / private ports as 5984, but I still cannot access CouchDb. Is there another step that I am missing that I need to setup?

Comment: Open up the port in the iptables firewall maybe?

Comment: I tried doing that using a command I found on another question here, but that didn't work.

Comment: To check if Azure is at fault, try mapping port 22 (SSH) to 5984 and see if it works. If it does, it is probably an in-VM config issue.

Comment: Yep I can SSH into the machine. I setup an http server in python and was able to hit that, but for some reason I cannot access CouchDb (or Redis for that matter either).

Comment: Actually I got Redis to work by removing the bind address in the config. I tried the same with couch, but it still isn't working. I also tried changing the port in `default.ini` but its not changing the port after a restart.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm having the same issue with ElasticSearch.  I did manage to see that both SSH (22) and RDP (3389) seem to work.

Comment: Nope never did get it working =\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just come across the answer for this.

You want the source port to be set to * and the destination port to be set to the correct port number.

Once this is done all will work correctly.